# Typescript SPFx Web part - As soon as I install bootstrap it started showing popperjs error in gulp serve

Tags: typescript, npm, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I created a spfx webpart using typescript. As soon as I installed the bootstrap its started showing the popperjs error.
here is my package.json look:

```
{
  "name": "test-webparts",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.12.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7": "0.2.3",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.12.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Here is the list of errors :

```
[18:08:10] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 274 ms
[18:08:10] Finished subtask 'sass' after 555 ms
[18:08:10] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[18:08:12] [tslint] tslint version: 5.12.1
[18:08:12] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[18:08:12] [tsc] typescript version: 3.7.7
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/createPopper.d.ts(1,73): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/applyStyles.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/applyStyles.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(1,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/arrow.d.ts(2,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/computeStyles.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/computeStyles.d.ts(1,67): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/eventListeners.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/eventListeners.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(1,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/flip.d.ts(2,40): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/hide.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/hide.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(1,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/offset.d.ts(2,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/popperOffsets.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/popperOffsets.d.ts(1,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(1,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/modifiers/preventOverflow.d.ts(2,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(1,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(2,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(3,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(3,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(4,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(4,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(5,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(5,37): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(6,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(6,45): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(7,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(8,36): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(9,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(9,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/types.d.ts(10,42): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:33] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:34] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(1,49): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:34] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[18:08:34] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/utils/detectOverflow.d.ts(2,65): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[18:08:35] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 23 s 
 exited with code 2
[18:08:35] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 25 s
```

I invested couple of days to figure out the issue but its still unresolved.
Let me know if you have any idea or suggestion about this error.
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
```

instead of

```
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';
```